# Need a .htaccess reroute exception when dealing with authentication in a child directory

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, htpasswd

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I added authentication to a directory "/pb" off the root of this and I'm getting redirected.  Is there any way I can add an exception to this rewrite rule to allow no rewrites when accessing /pb ?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Add `RewriteCond $1 !^(/pb)` right after `RewriteBase`